# Using aggregation to create and relate two different object members

Tags: c++

The goal of my program is to be able to have the user create up to 100 person and car objects each. Then I want to user to be able to "register" a car to a specific person. Doing research, I've found that aggregation would be the route to go. I'm *really* lost on how to implement this, though.

Right now I just have two classes and I relate a vector of the car objects to the person class:

```
class person{
public:
  vector<string>cars = new vector<string>();

};

class car{

//something

};
```

How would you relate these two? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have 1 person 'owning' a collection (vector) of cars.  What you want is that one car is owned by one person.

```
class car 
{
    person& _person;
    public void Register(Person& person) { _person = person; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not have a `person` know about a `car`, nor vice versa. Rather I think some external entity should relate them. In other words

```
class person
{
    // something
    std::string name;
};

class car
{
    // something
    std::string vin;
};
```

You could have the following class to aggregate the two

```
class driver
{
    // something
    car m_car;
    person m_owner;
}
```

Then you could make the following `vector` of 100 drivers, each of which have an associated `car` and `person`

```
std::vector<driver> owners = std::vector<driver>(100);
```

You can iterate through them as well to perform some actions if you want

```
for (auto& owner : owners)
{
    std::cout << "Current owner: " << owner.m_person.name << "\n"
              << "Associated vehicle: " << owner.m_car.vin << "\n"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! What would be the best way to enable to user to associate the two? Obviously I'm running a function but how would that function associate the user inputted car and person?

Comment: You could use some identifier of a unique `car` or `person`. In the above example this could be `person.name` or `car.vin`. If you have a collection of either, you could search against each person's name until you find the one that the user inputted, then make a new `driver` that associates them to the car. In that case the `driver` could also just have pointers or references instead of having a copy of the objects itself.